# Define the Fundamental Matrix of e, resulting in multiplication with Inverse Fundamental Matrix where t=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given A is a n×n matrix, Let $\phi(t)$ be a fundamental matrix for the homogeneous linear system $X' = Ax$.

Then the solution of the initial value problem $X' = AX,\ X(0)=X_0$ is given by $X(t) = \Phi(t)\Phi(0)^{-1}X_0$.

$e^{At}$ is defined as:
$$
e^{At} = I +At + \frac {A^2}2t^2 + ... +\frac {A^n}nt^n
$$
...which is an infinite expression. How can it be proven that
$$
e^{At} = \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0)
$$
even though it is a finite definition?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the solution is given by $X(t)  =  \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) X_0$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant - apologies for the typo.

Comment: Thanks for the fix!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$(e^{At})' = Ae^{At}, \tag 1$

and we also have

$(\Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(0))' = \Phi'(t) \Phi^{-1}(0); \tag 2$

since $\Phi(t)$ is a fundamental matrix solution,

$\Phi'(t) = A\Phi(t); \tag 3$

thus (2) yields

$(\Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(0))' = A\Phi(t) \Phi^{-1}(0); \tag 4$

comparing (1) and (4), we see that both $e^{At}$ and $\Phi(t)\Phi(0)$ satisfy a matrix differential equation of the form

$Z'(t) = AZ(t). \tag 5$

We next observe that at

$t = 0 \tag 6$

we have

$e^{A(0)} = e^0 = I, \tag 7$

and

$\Phi(0)\Phi^{-1}(0) = I \tag 8$

as well; thus $e^{At}$ and $\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0)$ each satisfy the same differential equation (5) with the same initial conditions (7)-(8); thus, by uniqueness of solutions,

$e^{At} = \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(t) \tag 9$

for all times $t$.

Another way to arrive at this result is to set

$W(t) = e^{-At}\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0); \tag{10}$

then

$W'(t) = (e^{-At})' \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) + e^{-At}(\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0))'$
$= -Ae^{-At} \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) + e^{-At} \Phi'(t)\Phi^{-1}(0); \tag{11}$

*via* (3) this becomes
e^
$W'(t) = -Ae^{-At} \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) + e^{-At} A\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0)$
$= -Ae^{-At} \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) + Ae^{-At} \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) = 0; \tag{12}$

thus

$W(t) = \text{constant} = W(0)$
$= e^{-A(0)}\Phi(0)\Phi^{-1}(0) = e^0\Phi(0)\Phi^{-1}(0) = I; \tag{13}$

combining (10) and (13) yields

$ e^{-At}\Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0) = I, \tag{14}$

that is,

$e^{At} = \Phi(t)\Phi^{-1}(0). \tag{15}$

Comment: Thank you very much!